# Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml. jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0:

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have the dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and during project build I receive the following error

```
 Failed to execute goal on project untitled3: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:untitled3:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.
jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:
jackson-core:pom:2.11.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.0/
jackson-core-2.11.0.pom: Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried to delete the dependency from local .m2 repository.

Is the repository down? Could there be another issue?

Comment: Which JDK version, Maven Version etc. are you using because `Received fatal alert: protocol_version... ` this looks like a problem with JDK7 or before ? Apart from using an older version of the dependency... newest 2.12.1... https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: thanks a lot your answer rocks! I had multiple jdk versions but maven was set up to work with JDK7. After changing to JDK8 project was built again. Please post as answer to get credits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message which is related to a JDK7 runtime with the Maven build. JDK7 is using by default TLSv1.1 but the https transport to Central has to use version TLSv1.2 at least.

The problem can be solved in two ways:

- Upgrade to JDK8
- Add `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` option to your Maven calls that should work as well.

But I strongly recommend to upgrade to JDK8 minimum.